# How to fix strange behavior of date picker UIView when changing screen orientation in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, constraints, screen-orientation

I have this project that requires to change the screen orientation of application once the user will pick a date using `datePicker`. Once the user tapped the `Date` button, It will show the `datePicker` The first image is the correct layout of the `datePicker` when **portrait** mode.

**Correct Portrait Layout**
[image: Correct Portrait Layout]

When changing the screen orientation from **Landscape to Portrait**. It will appear the issue. Please refer to image below.

**The datePicker is located below**
[image: Wrong Landscape Layout]

Which is the image below should be the correct layout once turned to landscape.

[image: Correct Landscape Layout]

When you changed the screen orientation back to portrait. The `datePicker` layout changed. Please refer to image below.

**Incorrect Portrait Layout**

[image: Wrong Portrait Layout]

Below are the codes used:

```
- (void)resizeView:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
//LOG(@"interfaceOrientation=%ld", (long)interfaceOrientation);
//LOG(@"self.frame =%@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.frame));
//LOG(@"self.bounds=%@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.bounds));

CGFloat x, y, w, h;
viewBack.frame = self.bounds;

#define _HEIGHT_LABEL   (40)
#define _HEIGHT_PICKER  (162)


#define _HEIGHT_TOOLBAR (CGRectGetHeight(toolBar.frame))//(44)
if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)
{
    LOG(@"[Portrait]");
    w = CGRectGetWidth(viewBack.frame);
    h = _HEIGHT_LABEL + _HEIGHT_PICKER*2 + _HEIGHT_TOOLBAR;
    viewPicker.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, w, h);
    viewPicker.center = viewBack.center;

    x = 0;
    y = 0;
    w = CGRectGetWidth(viewPicker.frame);
    h = _HEIGHT_LABEL;
    lblTitle.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, w, h);

    x = 0;
    y = CGRectGetMaxY(lblTitle.frame);
    w = CGRectGetWidth(viewPicker.frame);
    h = _HEIGHT_PICKER;
    datePicker.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, w, h);

    x = 0;
    y = CGRectGetMaxY(datePicker.frame);
    w = CGRectGetWidth(viewPicker.frame);
    h = CGRectGetHeight(datePicker.frame); //datePickerと同じ
    timePicker.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, w, h);

    x = 0;
    y = CGRectGetMaxY(timePicker.frame);
    w = CGRectGetWidth(viewPicker.frame);
    h = _HEIGHT_TOOLBAR;
    toolBar.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, w, h);
    //LOG(@"tool  =%@", NSStringFromCGRect(toolBar.frame));
}
    else if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
{
    LOG(@"[Landscape]");
    w = CGRectGetWidth(viewBack.frame);
    h = _HEIGHT_LABEL + _HEIGHT_PICKER + _HEIGHT_TOOLBAR;
    viewPicker.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, w, h);
    viewPicker.center = viewBack.center;

    x = 0;
    y = 0;
    w = CGRectGetWidth(viewPicker.frame);
    h = _HEIGHT_LABEL;
    lblTitle.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, w, h);

    w = CGRectGetWidth(viewPicker.frame) / 2; //画面幅の半分
    x = CGRectGetMidX(viewPicker.frame) - w;
    y = CGRectGetMaxY(lblTitle.frame);
    h = _HEIGHT_PICKER;
    datePicker.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, w, h);

    x = CGRectGetMidX(viewPicker.frame);
    y = CGRectGetMinY(datePicker.frame); //datePickerと同じ
    w = CGRectGetWidth(datePicker.frame); //datePickerと同じ
    h = CGRectGetHeight(datePicker.frame); //datePickerと同じ
    timePicker.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, w, h);

    x = 0;
    y = CGRectGetMaxY(datePicker.frame);
    w = CGRectGetWidth(viewPicker.frame);
    h = CGRectGetHeight(toolBar.frame);//44;
    toolBar.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, w, h);
}

 #if 0
LOG(@"back  =%@", NSStringFromCGRect(viewBack.frame));
LOG(@"base  =%@", NSStringFromCGRect(viewPicker.frame));
LOG(@"image =%@", NSStringFromCGRect(imageViewBlackGraBar.frame));
LOG(@"label =%@", NSStringFromCGRect(lblTitle.frame));
LOG(@"date  =%@", NSStringFromCGRect(datePicker.frame));
LOG(@"time  =%@", NSStringFromCGRect(timePicker.frame));
LOG(@"tool  =%@", NSStringFromCGRect(toolBar.frame));
LOG(@"");
 #endif
}
```

This is additional information I gathered during my investigation. Below is the **.xib** for portrait and landscape.

[image: Portrait][image: landscape]

Answer (score 0):

Try calling [[self view] layoutIfNeeded]; in resizeView

or [[self view] setNeedsLayout]; when orientation occurs.

use setNeedsLayout if you are okay with the system to update it in the next upcoming update cycle use layoutIfNeeded if you want it to be updated immediately.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried it but doesn't fix the issue :(

Answer (score 0):

You should use `UITextField` instead of `UILabel`
and just set date picker as textField's `inputView`.